# Python missing modules with Theano

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, machine-learning, deep-learning

i have installed theano a deep neural network library and am trying to run some examples, but it looks like the script cant find some of the modules. i tried setting path

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano
sys.path.append('/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano')
```

but both are not working. I get this error. I see that the modules are properly installed in subdirectory of theano /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/.. but somehow python cant seem to find the modules

Please can someone help. I am using a mac.

```
$python theano_mnist.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "theano_mnist.py", line 45, in <module>
    import theano
  File "/Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Desktop/theano.py", line 6, in <module>
    from theano.tensor.nnet import conv
ImportError: No module named tensor.nnet
```

Comment: Whenever you export kindly note that There should not be any space before and after '=' (equal to sign).

`export PYTHONPATH = /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano` 

should be changed to

    `export PYTHONPATH='/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano'`

And with respect to the Import Error 
ImportError: No module named tensor.nnet
Kindly check whether conv class or module exist in the targeted import path i.e theano.tensor.nnet.

Comment: Thank you, i did that not working :(

Comment: How did you install theano by the way? Did you tried `pip install theano`.

Comment: How is `/Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Desktop/theano.py` related to your program? It looks like this file is being loaded when you do `import theano` instead of real theano.

Comment: yes using pip install theano. i run the theano.py script i wrote, using python theano.py from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue on Theano repository. As fast solution I have:

1. Opened the file "miniconda3/envs/YOUR_CONDA_ENV_NAME/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/tensor/signal/downsample.py"
2. change the import `import pool` in `from . import pool`

and it works!